# jQuery's return value is Array, but constructor is Object. how?

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example,

```
$(document) // [ #document ] : document object in array
typeof $(document) // "object"
$(document).constructor // function Object() { [native code] } or function (a,b) { return some function; }
```

If value is array, it have to be Array constructor.

It's not an array like object. because array like object just has array property, not like [].

How can it be?

add:
If you can, show simple example code, please.
like

```
a = ... 
console.log(a) // [ ... ]
console.log(a.constructor) // function Object or something
```

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for why the return from `$(document)` is "not an array like object" - if you look at the actual jQuery source you'll find it _is_ an array-like object and _not_ an array...

Comment: @nnnnnn because array-like object is not shown as []

Comment: "Shown" where? The return from `$(document)` is an instance of `jQuery.fn.init` which has had `0` and `length` properties added. If it was an `Array` it would have array methods like `.join()` and it doesn't. _Look at the source code._

Comment: Thanks your answer. Actually I confused about concept of return instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the jQuery [source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=jQuery.fn.init).  `$(document)` creates a cloned jQuery object of the document element and then makes and returns an [array-like object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/).

> the jQuery factory function $() returns a jQuery object that has many
>   of the properties of an array (a length, the [] array access operator,
>   etc.), but is not exactly the same as an array and lacks some of an
>   array's built-in methods (such as .pop() and .reverse()).

Comment: Now I am confused. If it is returning an array of objects shouldn't its constructor give `function Array() {//..}`?

Comment: It doesn't make or return an array, it returns an instance of `jQuery.fn.init` after adding `0` and `length` properties. That is, it returns an array-like object.

Comment: Right, got it! The output is an object that have some properties of an array, but it is not an array.

Comment: Note: in the case of `$(document)` (and indeed most other cases) the `$()` function returns _before_ it gets to the last line that returns the result of `jQuery.makeArray()`. The array access operator `[]` isn't really "array access" because it applies to all JS objects.

Answer (score 0):

An array, as in `[]`, is also an object in JavaScript. In JS mostly everything is an object, such as functions, arrays, literal objects, regular expressions... To really know what you're dealing with is an array you can do this:

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(myarray) === '[object Array]'
```